Why do lighting snoots need to be long?
I have just been introduced to the concept of using lighting snoots to create a more focused circle of light with diffused edges.

They have a tube that gradually gets thinner with a honeycomb grid at the end. Now from reading other posts I understand that the honeycomb grid is essentially cutting rays of light that would have otherwise spread out (creating more diffused lighting) but I then dont quite get why this tube is so long? Does the honeycomb grid need to extend the whole way through it? Is it just at the end? If so what would happen if they just outright blocked the light outside of the honeycomb and put the honeycomb directly on the diffused light source?

This gets back to your etendue question. The angle at which light spreads depends on the angle of the light source as seen from the honeycomb.

So really the tube doesnt matter insofar as it is moving the honeycomb closer to where the light will be cast?
